# "The write timed out." in .net cf 3.5

Tags: .net, compact-framework, bluetooth, serial-port, zebra-printers

I want to write to Serial Port in an application written in .Net CF 3.5.

Device : Motorola MC75A6

OS:Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional

Printer: Zebra RW 420

I added printer via Bluetooth and assigned COM5 serial port.

i have code like this:

```
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM5");
        port.BaudRate = 19200;
        port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        port.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
        port.WriteTimeout = 5000;
        port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        if (!port.IsOpen)
            port.Open();
```

when i tried to write to port with code

```
        port.Write("why timed out");
```

i get error indicating that "The write timed out.".

This code works well in .NET CF 2.0.

Any advice?

Comment: Problem solved >> I've changed com port. First via Bluetooth, i assigned COM6 to discovered printer, and then i changed my code to use COM6, not COM5. "The write timed out" error has gone...

Comment: After a long hunt, i found that NET 3.5 is useLESS for SerialPort applications. It has many bugs, and using NET 2.0 is recommended for serial port apps.

Comment: Carsten Kanstrup has a WARNING about that! http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/3e64f562-e74b-4213-8019-e69f54fc0d74?prof=required

Comment: Was fixed in .net 3.5 sp1.